# How to subscribe/detect flash/AIR WARNING message: DisplayObject's filtered dimensions are too large to be drawn

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

**Scenario:**

A Flex 3.5 application where users are allowed to resize components via mouse (images, text) for designing an image. The user is working with a 'scaled' version on screen.

Later, an AIR application is used to render a non-scaled production image.

**Problem:**

Occasionally a user will drag/resize a component such that it becomes 'too large' for the player/AIR to render the (non-scaled) production version; triggering warning message like the following (in debugger/trace file):

***"Warning: Filter will not render.  The DisplayObject's filtered dimensions (181695, 2699) are too large to be drawn."***

**What I'm looking for:**

**Is there any way to *programmatically* capture/detect the warning message in my AIR application?**

I understand/know of the scenarios of *why* this warning happens (maximum sizes for display objects/filters/etc..) and I am planning on putting in constraints on the user actions so that the unscaled version will not trigger this warning (if at all possible).

However, for existing data, or (*gasp* - never!) bugs in my constraint logic, I'd love to be able to programmatically detect this warning that I can do other downstream workflow steps.

Answer (score 0):

The warning most likely comes from a `ShaderFilter`, however this class doesn't dispatch any events so you won't be able to programmatically detect this condition. You'll just have to manually check that the width and height of the display objects are below 2880.